# 401 error on LInkedIn Discussions

Tags: java, linkedin-api

We have a discussion link on our website, which navigates the user to the LinkedIn Discussions.

It worked fine about few days ago and now it goes to 401 error. Please Help.

The error log that I get is -

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/groups/4844082: (id,name,site-group-url,small-logo-url,large-logo-url)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1436)
at com.insideup.web.AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.getGroupInfoById(AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.java:842)
at com.insideup.web.AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.getLatestDicussion(AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.java:714)
at com.insideup.web.AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.showDiscussionPage(AdvertiserDashBoardMultiActionController.java:628)
```

Comment: Thats a 401 not a 404

Comment: Your post mentions 404, it should be 401 like the stacktrace.

Comment: 401 == authorization error. Check if your key is still valid.

Comment: How are you authenticating with the LinkedIn API? 401 would suggest a problem with these credentials.

Comment: Hi All,Thanks for your help.
Hari Shankar , can you please suggest how do I check the validity of my key.